# ngrx, How to have a starting state from an api?

Tags: ngrx

I have my reducer with a starting state of an empty array:

```
folderReducer(state:Array<Folder> = [], action: Action)
```

I'd like to populate the starting state, so when I do

```
store.subscribe(s => ..)
```

The first item I get comes from the database. I assume the way of doing this is with ngrx/effects, but I'm not sure how.

Comment: Yes it's with ngrx/effects. I've made a tuto on [stackoverflow documentation](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/angular2/8086/ngrx) and you can find a lot of great tutorial out there ;)

Comment: You could use a filter `store.select(x => x.user).filter(user => !!user)`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your store always has the *initial state*, that you define in the reducer-function. The *initial states* main purpose is to ensure that the application is able to start up and not run into any null-pointer-exceptions. And also it sets up your application to start making the first api-calls ect. - so you can think of it as a *technical initial state*.

If you want to fill your store with api-data on the startup, you would do that on the same way that you add/modify data during any other action - just that the action of *"initially loading data"* is not triggered by some user-interaction but through:

- either when your root-component loads
- or as part of a service in the constructor

In case you want to prevent specific components from showing anything until your API-call is done, you would have to adjust the display-components to display or hide data based on your state (e.g. by implementing a flag in your satet `initialDataLoaded`).

Answer (score 1):

A dynamic initial state is now supported, see: https://github.com/ngrx/platform/blob/master/docs/store/api.md#initial-state-and-ahead-of-time-aot-compilation

Also see: https://github.com/ngrx/platform/issues/51

I would only do this if the database is local, otherwise the request will hold up loading of the application.