# IONIC and NGRX set initial state from indexed db

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, local-storage, ngrx, ionic-native

I'm working in an Ionic app with angular and I want my state to be persistent so I added the plugin `@ionic/storage-angular` to save the current state and when I restart the app I want to set in ngrx the state previously saved.

So I created my storage service:

```
@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class StorageService {
    state: AppState;
    constructor(private storage: Storage, public store: Store<AppState>) {
      this.createDBStorage();
      this.loadStorage();
    }

    async createDBStorage() {
      await this.storage.create();
    }

    async loadStorage() {
      const dbState = await this.storage.get('dt-config');
      if (dbState) {
        this.state = dbState;
      } else {
        this.state = null;
      }
    }


    getState() {
      return this.state || null;
    }

    saveState(newState: AppState) {
      this.storage.set('dt-config', newState);
      this.state = newState;
    }
}
```

I researched about how to set the initial state from my indexed db and I found this ---> [How to set initialState in @ngrx/core with a promise from indexedDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47725517/how-to-set-initialstate-in-ngrx-core-with-a-promise-from-indexeddb)
but the answer is from three years ago.

According to that answer there is something like this to set the initial state in app.module.ts

```
export function getInitialState(): Promise<any> {
  return StorageService.dB.loadInitialState('app-state');
}

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    ...
    StoreModule.forRoot(reducers, {initialState: getInitialState}),
    ...
  ], bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

And that's exactly what I need the problem is how to call my service or if there is other way to access the item saved in the indexed db?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing this, you can initialize your state with the initial value. Once your application is initialized you can trigger `LoadAppState action` & on that action, you can use Effects & reducer to set your store.
Like:

```
## Dispatch action on app initialization
this.store.dispatch(LoadAppState());

###### Reducer ######
export const reducer = createReducer(initialState,
  on(LoadAppStateSuccess, (state, action) => ([...state, action.payload])),
)

###### Effects ######
loadAppState$ = createEffect(() => this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(LoadAppState),
    switchMap(() => StorageService.dB.loadInitialState('app-state')
      .pipe(
        map(appState => LoadAppStateSuccess({ payload: appState })),
        catchError(() => EMPTY)
      ))
    )
  );
```